# Scraping php-generated html tables in R

Tags: php, html, r, web-scraping

I want to scrape data from this website http://demo.istat.it/bilmens2012gen/index02.html
On the left there's a webform which passes the parameters to a php page which in turn outputs the resulting html tables and in a frame in the same page.
From the the first drop-down list there are 107 cities and from the second 12 months so I should manualy run 1.284 queries to collect the desired data.
Any suggestion for automating this process?
I used R and rvest library to scrape static html tables but since these tables are generated by the form parameters I don't know how to do. Wish I could the combination of the parameters (like "city1" "month1") and retrieve the html and later do my stuff to join the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a fairly straightforward scraping job. When you select buttons on the page, the browser just requests some html from the server and puts it into the main frame. The request is just encoded in the url in this format:

```
                                             Province (1 - 107)   Period (1 - 12)
                                                              |                 |
                                                              v                 v
http://demo.istat.it/bilmens2012gen/query1.php?lingua=ita&Pro=1&allrp=4&periodo=1&submit=Tavola
```

So you can do this to get all the urls:

```
urls <- do.call("c", 
                lapply(1:107, 
                       function(x) paste0("http://demo.istat.it/bilmens2012gen/",
                                          "query1.php?lingua=ita&Pro=", x,
                                          "&allrp=4&periodo=", 1:12,
                                          "&submit=Tavola")
                  )
)
```

Of course, you still need to scrape the data from these pages. Here's an example of a function that will get the data from each link:

```
get_table <- function(url) 
{
  df <- xml2::read_html(url) %>%
  html_nodes("table") %>% 
  `[`(2) %>% html_table()
  df <- df[[1]]
  breaks <- which(df[,1] == "CodiceComune")
  output <- df[(breaks[1] + 2):(breaks[2] - 1),]
  output <- setNames(output, paste(df[1,], df[2,]))
  for(i in 3:8) output[[i]] <- as.numeric(as.character(output[[i]]))
  dplyr::as_tibble(output)
}
```

So I can get the first period of the first region like this:

```
get_table(urls[1])
#> # A tibble: 315 x 11
#>    `CodiceComune T~ `Comuni Totale` `Popolazioneini~ `Nati Vivi Tota~ `Morti Totale`
#>    <chr>            <chr>                      <dbl>            <dbl>          <dbl>
#>  1 001269           Strambino                   6314                1              5
#>  2 001270           Susa                        6626                2             10
#>  3 001271           Tavagnasco                   812                0              1
#>  4 001272           Torino                    869312              749           1011
#>  5 001273           Torrazza Piemo~             2833                2              4
#>  6 001274           Torre Canavese               592                1              1
#>  7 001275           Torre Pellice               4514                4              8
#>  8 001276           Trana                       3877                2              5
#>  9 001277           Trausella                    132                0              1
#> 10 001278           Traversella                  351                0              0
#> # ... with 305 more rows, and 6 more variables: `SaldoNaturale Totale` <dbl>, `Iscritti
#> #   Totale` <dbl>, `Cancellati Totale` <dbl>, `Saldomigratorio e per altri motivi Totale` <chr>,
#> #   `Unità inpiù/menodovute avariazioniterritoriali Totale` <chr>, `Popolazionefine periodo
#> #   Totale` <chr>
```

Of course, you would want to set up a loop to get all the pages and glue the data frames together, perhaps like this:

```
result_list <- list()
for(i in seq_along(urls))
{
  cat("Getting url", i, "of", length(urls), "\n")
  result_list[[i]] <- get_table(urls[i])
}
result_df <- do.call(rbind, result_list)
```

Obviously I have not tested this as it is likely to take about an hour to download and process all the tables.